# Filtering Content With Ranges

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'm creating a spreadsheet with a lot of content that I'd like to filter.

Let's say I have following headers:

Name, Height, Bloom Season, Bloom Color, pH, Zone

And some of the following content:
Dwarf Sunspot Sunflower, 24-36", Summer, Yellow, 5.5-6.2, 3-9
Borage (Blue), 24", Summer, Blue, 6.6-7.3, 3-9
Fireweed, 36-48", Early Summer-Late Summer, Pink, , 4-8

How can I organize this content so I can easily find flowers that grow in Zone 3 with yellow bloom colors?

As its currently structured, in my Zone filter window I'd get things such as 3-9,4-8,... and I'd have to go through each one to see if its in my target range.

I could split columns like Zone into Zone Low and Zone High, but then I'd have to deselect everything in my Zone Low and then select only the things equal or higher than my number, then go to Zone High and repeat the process.

What is the best approach on how I should organize my content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rather SORT your whole table based on "zone" (as it will then sort everything starting from "1-2" to "4-5" etc.) and then you can filter flowers based on color. But as you have also height, you cannot really sort but using either height OR zone - unless you are willing to fetch the data into new cells/tables dynamically instead of "just" filtering and sorting?

If you are willing to do some Excel magic or VBA script, you can just separate heightMin and heightMax columns as well as zoneMin and zoneMax etc. and then fetch what you want cell-by-cell, giving you more opportunities for complex searches.